# To set the ws1 and ws2 to the sheets of chosen file after the prompt by a macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code Both the pieces of code work fine separately, but when combined it gives an error

> "Object Variable not set "

It needs the ws1 and ws2 to be set in sheets of new workbook that's opened. I tried with this workbook and active workbook, but it considers the work book in which the macro is there, but not the newly chosen file.

The below code asks to select a file and then compares 2 sheets of data and displays the difference in a new workbook (But I want it to display the difference in 3rd sheet how do I do that). I'm new to VBA.

```
Private Sub AutomateCompare()
    Dim fileBrowse As FileDialog
    Dim shtNum As Integer

    Set fileBrowse = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    If fileBrowse.Show = True Then wbPath = fileBrowse.SelectedItems(1)

    With Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
        shtNum = InputBox("Enter the number of the sheet you want to use.")
    End With
End Sub


Sub Compare2Worksheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)
    Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer
    Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
    Dim report As Workbook, difference As Long
    Dim row As Long, col As Integer
    Set report = Workbooks.Add

    With ws1.UsedRange
        ws1row = .Rows.Count
        ws1col = .Columns.Count
    End With

    With ws2.UsedRange
        ws2row = .Rows.Count
        ws2col = .Columns.Count
    End With

    maxrow = ws1row
    maxcol = ws1col

    If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
    If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col

    difference = 0

    For col = 1 To maxcol
        For row = 1 To maxrow
            colval1 = ""
            colval2 = ""
            colval1 = ws1.Cells(row, col).Formula
            colval2 = ws2.Cells(row, col).Formula

            If colval1 <> colval2 Then
                difference = difference + 1
                Cells(row, col).Formula = colval1 & "<> " & colval2
                Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = 255
                Cells(row, col).Font.ColorIndex = 2
                Cells(row, col).Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next row 
    Next col

    Columns("a:b").ColumnWidth = 25
    report.Saved = True

    If difference = 0 Then
        report.Close False
    End If
    Set report = Nothing

    MsgBox difference & " cells contain different data! ", vbInformation, "comparing two worksheets"
End Sub


Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Call AutomateCompare
    Call Compare2Worksheets(ws1, ws2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the `Sheet` object: `Sheet("MySheetNo3").Cells(row, column).Value = ...`.

Comment: Thank you I will try with this

Answer (score 0):

To get worksheet from your AutomateCompare() procedure, change it into Function:

```
private Function AutomateCompare() As Worksheet
Dim fileBrowse As FileDialog
Dim shtNum As Integer
Set fileBrowse = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
If fileBrowse.Show = True Then wbPath = fileBrowse.SelectedItems(1)
With Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
    shtNum = InputBox("Enter the number of the sheet you want to use.")
    Set AutomateCompare = .Sheets(shtNum)
End With
End Sub
```

Then, when calling it, set ws1. You still have to somehow set ws2.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = AutomateCompare()
Set ws2 = ??
Call Compare2Worksheets(ws1, ws2)
End Sub
```

UPDATE:

```
Sub start()

Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = AutomateCompare()
Set ws2 = AutomateCompare()
Call Compare2Worksheets(ws1, ws2)
End Sub


Private Function AutomateCompare() As Worksheet
Dim fileBrowse As FileDialog
Dim shtNum As Integer
Set fileBrowse = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
If fileBrowse.Show = True Then wbPath = fileBrowse.SelectedItems(1)
With Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
    shtNum = InputBox("Enter the number of the sheet you want to use.")
    Set AutomateCompare = .Sheets(shtNum)
End With
End Function


Sub Compare2Worksheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)
    Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer
    Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
    Dim report As Workbook, difference As Long
    Dim row As Long, col As Integer
    Set report = Workbooks.Add

    With ws1.UsedRange
        ws1row = .Rows.Count
        ws1col = .Columns.Count
    End With

    With ws2.UsedRange
        ws2row = .Rows.Count
        ws2col = .Columns.Count
    End With

    maxrow = ws1row
    maxcol = ws1col

    If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
    If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col

    difference = 0

    For col = 1 To maxcol
        For row = 1 To maxrow
            colval1 = ""
            colval2 = ""
            colval1 = ws1.Cells(row, col).Formula
            colval2 = ws2.Cells(row, col).Formula

            If colval1 <> colval2 Then
                difference = difference + 1
                Cells(row, col).Formula = colval1 & "<> " & colval2
                Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = 255
                Cells(row, col).Font.ColorIndex = 2
                Cells(row, col).Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next row
    Next col

    Columns("a:b").ColumnWidth = 25
    report.Saved = True

    If difference = 0 Then
        report.Close False
    End If
    Set report = Nothing

    MsgBox difference & " cells contain different data! ", vbInformation, "comparing two worksheets"
End Sub
```

Comment: But both ws1 and ws2 have to be set to the particular sheets right ?how do we do it?

Comment: @Suchithra In AutomateCompare user is asked to choose a file. Then, Excel will open this file and ask for sheet number. That sheet will be returned by function and set to wariable in `Set ws1 = AutomateCompare()`.

Comment: @Suchithra Update your code in question and write where is the problem, please. Remember that you can debug your code by putting cursor somewhere in the method and press F8 to run code line by line. Setting some watches will help you find out what your variables are.

Comment: Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
       Set ws1 = AutomateCompare()
       Call Compare2Worksheets(ws1, ws2)
       End Sub

Comment: I just wrote this to check if it works for ws1 but it gives the same error at ws1.usedrange
And I changed the name to     private Function AutomateCompare() As Worksheet as well

Comment: @Suchithra Did you add `Set AutomateCompare = .Sheets(shtNum)` in your Function?

Comment: Yes I did that, It takes input for the sheet but again it gives an error at ws1.usedrange

Comment: @Suchithra I just checked code from my updated answer and it's working fine, at least for getting worksheets from files.

Comment: @Suchithra Let me know if you have any troubles with my answer.

Comment: Yes. It gets worksheets from files, after that it gives the same error at ws1.usedrange.

Comment: @Suchithra Are you sure you are passing an existing index of worksheet in input box? Did you try debugging it to check if you get a proper worksheet from input box?